# Stubborn Exterior Mildew

Tags: wood, mold, siding

This is a photo of mildew on the underside of a porch ceiling stained with Rubio Hybrid Wood Protector with extra M1 Mildewcide added: https://imgur.com/a/lbMsHS1. The substrate is Doug Fir, which was stored under cover, then sanded and stained on the bench, prior to installing in Aug 2023. Zero water exposure - except for our copious morning dew (central TX).

I've removed mildew in this exact situation (same stain, same building), except the substrate was Southern Pine, using diluted bleach. But I've never seen mildew here (central TX) that looks quite like this -- and *nothing* will get it off. I tried diluted bleach at the usual dwell time before scrubbing, then 20 min, 30 min, and 1 hour. I tried 70% alcohol, hydrogen peroxide, vinegar, and pure bleach. I could try your favorite magic cleaner... but it's hard to imagine when bleach does *nothing* (except wear the surface of the wood).

Thoughts? Again the only variable (compared to situations in which I got the mildew off no problem w/bleach solution) is that it's Doug Fir.